# Android Map Fragment works properly in first activity but in second activity it shows up but is hardly responsive

Tags: android, android-tabhost, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment, fragment-tab-host

I am working on an **android** application which uses **googlemaps api-2**

**Issue** : A map fragment in main activity displays properly and does functionality as required .But a Map fragment which is included in the next activity which includes a tab host displays a **unresponsive map** .
**First it takes lot of time to load showing grey grids on map** and **after almost a minute** some clicks on the map it **shows up** but still is really, i mean really slow .I tested this application on genymotion virtual device also tested on my nexus phone, still things dint change.
I wanted to post pictures but i dont have enough reputation to do so.

**Solutions that dint work** :
1. Using appropriate user permissions in Android Manifest file

1. Adding SupportMapFragment using programmatic approach rather than including in xml layout.
2. Adding SupportMapFragment in xml layout .
3. I have high speed internet so network connection is also not an issue

Code :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final float zoom = 15;
    Button goButton;
    Button setCurrentSource;
    Button setCurrentDestination;
    public static  GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationClient mLocationClient;
    Geocoder gc;
    List<Address> list ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         gc = new Geocoder(this);
        final EditText SourceAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sourceAddressEditText);
        final EditText DestinationAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.destinationAddressEditText);
        goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        setCurrentSource = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setCurrentSource);
        setCurrentDestination =(Button)findViewById(R.id.setCurrentDestination);


        if(servicesOk()){
            if(initMap())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Ready to Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
                mLocationClient.connect();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Map not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

setCurrentSource.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    /*Some code*/   
        });

        setCurrentDestination.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    /*Some code*/
        });



        SourceAddress.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        /*Some code*/

        });

DestinationAddress.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        /*Some code*/
        });

        final String source  = SourceAddress.getText().toString();
        final String destination = DestinationAddress.getText().toString();
        Log.d("source",source);
        Log.d("destination",destination);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RouteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("source", SourceAddress.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("destination", DestinationAddress.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        });
    }

    protected void gotolocation(LatLng ll) {
    /*Some code*/}


    public boolean initMap(){

        if(mMap == null){
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap =mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
        }


}
```

activity_main.xml :(Which works properly)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.knowthysubway.Activities.MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/app_back">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/destinationAddressEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:text="@string/goButton"
        style="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_light_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destinationAddressTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sourceAddressEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="@string/DestinationAddressTextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    **<fragment 
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/goButton"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

      />**

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sourceAddressEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/destinationAddressEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sourceAddressTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/setCurrentDestination"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceAddressTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sourceAddressEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="@string/SourceAddressTextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/destinationAddressEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/destinationAddressTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/setCurrentDestination"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setCurrentSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sourceAddressEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sourceAddressEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/setCurrentSource" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setCurrentDestination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/setCurrentSource"
        android:layout_below="@+id/destinationAddressTextView"
        android:text="@string/setCurrentDestination" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tab host activity.java which has Tab for Map Display :

```
package com.example.knowthysubway.Activities;

import com.example.knowthysubway.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;


public class RouteActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    TabHost tabhost;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    LocalActivityManager man;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_view);
        man = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        man.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tabhost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabhost.setup(man);
        String source =      getIntent().getExtras().getString("source");
        String destination = getIntent().getExtras().getString("destination");

        TabSpec spec1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("Map View");
        Intent intent1= new Intent(this,MapActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("source1", source);
        intent1.putExtra("destination1", destination);
        spec1.setContent(intent1);


        TabSpec spec2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Text View");
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,ListActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("source1", source);
        intent2.putExtra("destination1", destination);

        spec2.setContent(intent2);

        tabhost.addTab(spec1);
        tabhost.addTab(spec2);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Tab host XML file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The Buggy code  :** 
**MapActivity.java**

```
package com.example.knowthysubway.Activities;

import com.example.knowthysubway.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private static final float zoom = 15;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFrag =null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_route);

         mMapFrag = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.maproute,mMapFrag).commit();
        mMap =mMapFrag.getMap();
    }
```

Map_route.xml :Where the unresponsive map lies and also tried including fragment tag in this xml still the map stays unresponsive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom ="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.knowthysubway.Activities.MapActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/maproute">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest file  :

```
  <permission android:name="com.example.knowthysubway.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.knowthysubway.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

*Update:*

I am still not sure what is the problem but i had to make it work a different way since dint get any fruiful help. There might be some interference between using Tab host activity with Map because when i removed the Tab host and kept a menu button instead things worked fine. I am still not sure why it dint work with TABHOST.

Comment: I am still not sure what is the problem but i had to make it work a different way since dint get any fruiful help. There might be some interference between using Tab host activity with Map because when i removed the Tab host and kept a menu button instead things worked fine. I am still not sure why it dint work with TABHOST.